# Will ActiveRecord:link() method fail or pass on on incorrect data?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

When using [`ActiveRecord:link()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) method, am I forced to update relations in a "secure" way:

```
foreach ($postData['User']['lab'] as $labId) {
    $lab = Lab::findOne($labId);

    if ($lab instanceof \app\models\Lab) {
        $model->link('lab', $lab);
    }
}
```

Or can I do this, the "lazy" way:

```
foreach ($postData['User']['lab'] as $labId) {
    $model->link('lab', Lab::findOne($labId));
}
```

Without caring for extra checkings?

Will `link` fail or pass on, if its feed with `null` (because call to `Lab::findOne($labId)` won't find given record on certain iteration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give error as far as i see from code.

With via in relation or without it calls methods from `$model` and if `Lab::findOne($labId)` is `null` - you'll get an error.

```
    if ($relation->via !== null) {
            if ($this->getIsNewRecord() || $model->getIsNewRecord()) {
......
    else {
        $p1 = $model->isPrimaryKey(array_keys($relation->link));
......
```

And as documentation says:

`Note that this method requires that the primary key value is not null.`